# Evaluate arguments and pass them to new file

Tags: r, eval, metaprogramming

*Sorry for the confusing title and this might be a confusing question as well but I will try my best to explain.*

Below is a very simplified example of my function. My original function is complex with many more arguments.

I have a function -

```
library(magrittr) #for pipes

parent_fn <- function(x = 5, y = 1, z = 10) {
  xy <- function() {
    x + y
  }
  create_file_from_function(xy, 'fn.R')
}
```

and `create_file_from_function` is defined as

```
create_file_from_function <- function(fn, path) {
  fn_str <- deparse(substitute(fn))
  fn %>%
    capture.output() %>%
    head(-1) %>% #To remove the last line "<environment: 0x....>"
    paste0(collapse = '\n') %>%
    paste(fn_str, '<-', .) %>%
    cat(file = path)
}
```

What `create_file_from_function` does is it copies the body of the function in a new file as passed in `path`.

When I call

```
parent_fn()
```

In my working directory it creates a new file `fn.R` with the text -

```
xy <- function() {
    x + y
}
```

However, what I would like to have is the below -

```
xy <- function() {
    5 + 1
}
```

which means the default values from `parent_fn` should be evaluated and passed in the new file.

Similarly, below are some more function calls and expected output just to make sure I have explained my problem clearly.

`parent_fn` call :

```
parent_fn(x = 10)
```

Expected output in `fn.R`

```
xy <- function() {
    10 + 1
}
```

`parent_fn` call :

```
parent_fn(x = 10, y = 2)
```

Expected output in `fn.R`

```
xy <- function() {
    10 + 2
}
```

I have tried using `eval` and did some other attempts looking online but honestly, I have no idea how I can achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substitute()` and pass the variables to its environment argument:

```
parent_fn <- function(x = 5, y = 1, z = 10, out = "fn.R") {
  f <- substitute(`<-`(xy, function() { 
    x + y
    }), list(x = x, y = y, z = z))
  writeLines(deparse(f), out)
  }

parent_fn()
```

Generates a file containing:

```
xy <- function() {
    5 + 1
}
```